# flutter android Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'

Tags: flutter, flutter-android, flutter-webrtc

I am using `flutter webrtc package` but i want try to create apk i am getting below
error.
`flutter doctor` commands shows everything is correct.
I am using latest 3.9 version of flutter. I already tried `flutter clean` many times

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find android-104.5112.03.jar (com.github.webrtc-sdk:android:104.5112.03).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jitpack.io/com/github/webrtc-sdk/android/104.5112.03/android-104.5112.03.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

*
```

Answer (score 0):

For whoever reaches this question in the future, you should use GitHub as a source in your `pubspec` file instead of a version:

```
flutter_webrtc:
  git: https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc
```

This fixed the error for me.

Reference: https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc/issues/1184